# guide to correctly assemble a Walmart bike

Tags: maintenance, repair

I bought a genesis max air from Walmart last fall used it a few times before the winter and two weeks ago brought it back out.  For the last two weeks me and the wife have been riding about 8 miles everyday and went and rode some trails last Sunday.  So far the bike has been alright but I think I would feel better if I reassembled it.  So I was seeing if someone knew of a guide or video on how to tear it down and put it back together or really any suggestions on it.

Problems I've already noticed is the front derailer won't shift into third it's like the cable is all the way tight in second and the disc on the front wheel is sitting way too tight in the brake.  I don't have any experience working on bikes but I own a construction Company and am a trained mechanic (I service all of my equipment) so I think I could figure it out with some help.

Comment: Not sure if you can find a manual for that specific bike, but it's probably not a good idea to disassemble the entire bike and reassemble it. This will require quite a few specialized tools that you probably don't own.  It's probably best to adjust the parts that you know you are having problems with.  The brakes and derailleur can be fixed with very basic tools (screwdriver or hex key) which most people will have or can acquire for a very small amount. Look around on this site and others to find information how to fix specific problems. As more specific questions if you can't find answers.

Comment: In general, a BSO like this will be tricky to keep in adjustment.

Comment: Thanks I really wasn't sure what the best way to go about it would be so I'll work on getting my current problems solved.

Comment: @Kibbee: not only that, but the tools to do job will cost more than the bike.

Comment: @whatsisname Maybe if you were starting off from absolutely no tools, but judging from the fact that the OP is a trained mechanic, he could probably get his hands on a few of the basics for free.  The only really specialty tools you'd need to pretty much disassemble the entire bike is a crank puller, a bottom bracket tool, a freewheel remover, and a chain whip. You could probably get all those for under $50 if you weren't picky about quality. Also, you could find a bike co-op in your area and not have to buy any tools. Regardless, it's probably a bad idea to disassemble the entire bike.

Answer (score 1):

If you are mechanically inclined most of the adjustments are straight forward. There are many on line tutorials, Park Tools website and the often mentioned Sheldon Brown are my personal favorites. As @ Batman has stated BSO (bicycle shaped object) can be frustrating to maintain. I have serviced them and the bearings don't get any smoother when I assemble it than it did from the factory. The primary concern from the design is will it function (not is it smooth ,is it light ,is it durable)  with parts from a certain pricepoint To use a comparison you may relate to. If I buy a tablesaw for $125 it may last me 20 years of occasional homeowner use, if you used it commercially it will fail much sooner. A Walmart grade bicycle will function fine for an occasional ride before it needs maintenance. A higher quality bike (not just when new but after years of use) will be easier to tune and stay in tune longer. It will be repairable and upgradable.